# How do I retrieve the PostgreSQL commands which create the tables and functions in my database?

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-schema

I have a database which I have several tables (including some data) and functions on. I created these tables and functions from the command line interface.

My question is: Is there any way to have my database queries back which creates the same tables/functions again in a readable format.

PostgreSQL version: 9.1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pg_dump --schema-only my_database > my_database.sql
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html